# how can I get result from ngbModal component

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4, ng-bootstrap

I need help with getting results from ngbModal component.

I open the modal with a link

```
<a class="order-collection-options-link" (click)="openTimePicker()">{{'ORDER_COLLECTION_OPTIONS_LABEL' | dict}}</a>
```

here is my openTimePicker() method

```
openTimePicker() {
    const modalRef =     this.modalService.open(DateTimePickerModalComponent);
    console.log(modalRef.componentInstance);
}
```

my DateTimePickerModalComponent.
It has two buttons APPLY and OK and each emits event onApplySelection and onConfirmSelection ...

```
@Component({
  selector: 'date-time-picker-modal',
  styleUrls: ['./dateTimePickerModal.component.scss'],
  templateUrl: './dateTimePickerModal.component.html',
})

export class DateTimePickerModalComponent {

private selection : Date[] = [];

  @Output() onApplySelection: EventEmitter<Date> = new EventEmitter<Date>();
  @Output() onConfirmSelection: EventEmitter<Date[]> = new EventEmitter<Date[]>()

    ...


}
```

So I need to know how to attach my "parent" component to those events in open() method ..

Answer (score 0):

After more searching the net this is what I came up with and it's supposed to be propper way to do it. Note my components aren't realy in PARENT CHILD relation .. so I implemented service and used subscribe methods.

```
@Injectable()
export class DateTimePickerModalService {

  private confirmedSelectionSource = new Subject<Date[]>();
  private appliedSelectionSource = new Subject<Date>();

  confirmedSelection$ = this.confirmedSelectionSource.asObservable();
  appliedSelection$ = this.appliedSelectionSource.asObservable();


  constructor() {

  }

  confirmSelection(selection : Date[]) {
    this.confirmedSelectionSource.next(selection);
  }


  applySelection(selectedDate : Date) {
    this.appliedSelectionSource.next(selectedDate);
  }

}
```

and added it to app.modules.ts in providers []

and in my service that needs to be informmed on these changes I implemented subscribe() methods

```
constructor(..., private dateTimePickerModalService: DateTimePickerModalService) {
    ...
    dateTimePickerModalService.confirmedSelection$.subscribe(
      days => {
        console.log('got days:', days);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error');
      }
    );
    dateTimePickerModalService.appliedSelection$.subscribe(
      day => {
        console.log('got day:', day);
      },
      error => {
        console.log('error');
      }
    );
```

}